# Passing DataKeys between pages

Tags: asp.net

Using a GridView on the default page and want to show details of the row selected on another page.  The code for capturing and sending the datakey is -

```
protected void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            Response.Redirect("InvoicePage.aspx? EntityID= " + GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()); 
}
```

And the code for retrieving the value is -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["EntityID"];
}
```

My problem is that the id variable is a null on the receiving page.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL should look something like this: `InvoicePage.aspx?EntityID="`, No space before or after `EntityID`

Answer (score 0):

By The way  Remove the white space : aspx?**<>**EntityID***<>*=

```
protected void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            string id = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("InvoicePage.aspx?EntityID="+id); 
}
```

Try to add :

```
private string _EntityId;

    //To check  if value pass on query string 
    //but this is not really required if you want
    public string EntityId
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString["EntityID"] != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _EntityId = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["EntityID"].ToString());

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _EntityId="0";
                    }

                    return _EntityId;
                }
            }


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Request.QueryString["EntityID"].ToString(); 
    string id = EntityId;
}
```

Regads